# Do grama devathas have capability of giving moksha?

Tags: scripture, moksha, goddess

Krishna, Rama, Hanuman, Siva, etc., are capable of giving moksha to an aspirant.

Is it valid for Grama Devatas (village goddess) as well?

Comment: I don't think, it's that easy. Each sect would say only their Parameśvara is the final sanctioning capable authority for Moksha. With the local devtãs, they are more revered for material purposes or daily day to day life purposes.